# Few Portlets not coming in WebSphere Portal Server v8.5

Tags: java, portal, websphere-portal

I am migrating my code from WebSphere Portal 7 to WebSphere Portal 8.5... 
In WPS 7 all were dislayed properly but in WPS 8.5 only 1 portlet is appearing rest of the portlets are not appearing... All the layouts and skins are completely fine. The WAR file was compiled with WPS 8.5 libray and Java 7.. Also in the logs I cannot find any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the Error messages from the SystemOut.log.

We had some similar issues - some IBM API related usage might cause this problem.